# Best Way to restrict the list of maven modules during releasing

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, release

I am maintaining a java open source project [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit) which uses maven. To easily embed it including all helping modules into my IDE, I maintain a module-list in the parent pom that is quite long.
When I do the releases, I had to make sure, that the deployment for these modules get suppressed, because I don't want to see them on maven central.
Better would be to automatically suppress certain modules from releasing.

Does anyone know a simple way, probably using profiles, but during releasing I would like to avoid having to use profiles.

Comment: Based on what I've looked into the list only contains eight modules? Quite long? We have different opinions of long lists...Apart from that why would you like to release only parts of that? They belong all to your project which you would like to offer to users of your project?...

Comment: Hello, you are right, the list could be longer (and is longer, if you include all examples which come indirectly), but I don't want to trash maven central with modules which are not important to be used by others, which could get renamed, deleted ... But you are right, at least the tests-module should be built during release ... on the other side is travis-ci quite thorough.

Comment: The question which comes into my mind. If those modules are not important why do they exist?

Comment: They exist to structure the development, to show examples. They do not exist to be used as artifacts by others. They are important, for documentation, tests, tutorials. It is important, that the travis-ci builds and tests them, but I do not want and I think it makes no sense to upload them to Maven Central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make another `pom.xml` (let call it first)
2. Include your main pom in first as module (remove all externals from it)
3. Include all external modules in first as well.
4. Open first in your IDE

You can store first in other VCS or just local.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, first would be stored in an extra directory like ide or so? I hoped, there would be a way to avoid an extra pom.

Comment: Yes. And there is a way, You can import multiple pom in your IDE.